# Grid height and width data-binding not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to get updates on the width/height values of a grid in XAML when their respective values change e.g. The user resizes the main window. I'm not sure why it isn't working. In the example below the binding is working for updating the Rectangle's Visibility's and SelectedViewTxt which are essentially coded in the same manner:

(Ignore the buttons/commands. They are working correctly and have no relevance to the question)

Any insights/feedback is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

BindingBase:

```
public class BindingBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : BindingBase
    {
        public Command Cmd1x1 { get; set; }
        public Command Cmd2x2 { get; set; }
        public Command Cmd3x3 { get; set; }
        public Command Cmd4x4 { get; set; }
        public Command Cmd5x5 { get; set; }

        private string selectedViewTxt;
        public string SelectedViewTxt
        {
            get { return selectedViewTxt; }
            set
            {
                selectedViewTxt = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(selectedViewTxt));
            }
        }

        private double viewWidth;
        public double ViewWidth
        {
            get { return viewWidth; }
            set
            {
                viewWidth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(viewWidth));
                WidthChanged();
            }
        }

        private double viewHeight;
        public double ViewHeight
        {
            get { return viewHeight; }
            set
            {
                viewHeight = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(viewHeight));
                HeightChanged();
            }
        }

        private Visibility rec1Visible;
        public Visibility Rec1Visible
        {
            get { return rec1Visible; }
            set
            {
                rec1Visible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(rec1Visible));
            }
        }

        private Visibility rec2Visible;
        public Visibility Rec2Visible
        {
            get { return rec2Visible; }
            set
            {
                rec2Visible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(rec2Visible));
            }
        }

        private Visibility rec3Visible;
        public Visibility Rec3Visible
        {
            get { return rec3Visible; }
            set
            {
                rec3Visible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(rec3Visible));
            }
        }

        private Visibility rec4Visible;
        public Visibility Rec4Visible
        {
            get { return rec4Visible; }
            set
            {
                rec4Visible = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(rec4Visible));
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Cmd1x1 = new Command(Change1x1);
            Cmd2x2 = new Command(Change2x2);
            Cmd3x3 = new Command(Change3x3);
            Cmd4x4 = new Command(Change4x4);
            Cmd5x5 = new Command(Change5x5);

            SelectedViewTxt = "1x1";

            Rec1Visible = Visibility.Visible;
            Rec2Visible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Rec3Visible = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Rec4Visible = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        private void WidthChanged()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"View Width: {this.ViewWidth}");
        }

        private void HeightChanged()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"View Height: {this.ViewHeight}");
        }

        public void Change1x1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1x1");
            SelectedViewTxt = "1x1";
        }

        public void Change2x2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2x2");
            SelectedViewTxt = "2x2";
        }

        public void Change3x3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("3x3");
            SelectedViewTxt = "3x3";
        }

        public void Change4x4()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("4x4");
            SelectedViewTxt = "4x4";
        }

        public void Change5x5()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("5x5");
            SelectedViewTxt = "5x5";
        }
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel Vm = new ViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this.Vm;
    }

    private void GridView_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("gridView size changed event fired");
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="VideoWallTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VideoWallTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="gridMain">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="gridView"
              SizeChanged="GridView_SizeChanged"
              Width="{Binding ViewWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              Height="{Binding ViewHeight, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

            <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Fill="Red" Visibility="{Binding Rec1Visible}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect2" Fill="Blue" Visibility="{Binding Rec2Visible}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect3" Fill="Yellow" Visibility="{Binding Rec3Visible}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="rect4" Fill="Green" Visibility="{Binding Rec4Visible}" />

        </Grid>

        <Grid x:Name="gridBtns" Grid.Row="1" Background="DarkGray">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Width="50" Content="1x1" x:Name="btn1x1" Command="{Binding Cmd1x1}"/>
                <Button Width="50" Content="2x2" x:Name="btn2x2" Command="{Binding Cmd2x2}"/>
                <Button Width="50" Content="3x3" x:Name="btn3x3" Command="{Binding Cmd3x3}"/>
                <Button Width="50" Content="4x4" x:Name="btn4x4" Command="{Binding Cmd4x4}"/>
                <Button Width="50" Content="5x5" x:Name="btn5x5" Command="{Binding Cmd5x5}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedViewTxt, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                           Margin="10,0,0,0"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `OnPropertyChanged` in `ViewModel` you should use the name of the public property instead of the name of the private field.

Example

Wrong

```
private double viewHeight;
public double ViewHeight
{
    get { return viewHeight; }
    set
    {
        viewHeight = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(viewHeight));
        HeightChanged();
    }
}
```

Correct

```
private double viewHeight;
public double ViewHeight
{
    get { return viewHeight; }
    set
    {
        viewHeight = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewHeight));
        HeightChanged();
    }
}
```

Similar for other properties.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, someone correct me if I'm wrong but I think the binding is not case sensitive. This is why the binding still works for SelectedViewTxt and Rec1Visible etc.

Comment: Regardless I will update that now since I'm assuming that using the public property is the standard

Comment: @DavidAndrewThorpe You are wrong. Binding is case sensitive, and the property name is case sensitive. You have to fire the PropertyChanged event with the property name, not the name of the backing field. And binding to a property does of course work once even when you use the wrong property name in the PropertyChanged event. The binding will just not update when the source property has changed.

Comment: @Clemens Okay I am wrong but my other bindings were working prior to changing the case and this answer doesn't fix the problem to my question either so I'm not sure what to say.

Comment: They were working once, without update. Be aware that PropertyChanged is not necessary for a working binding, but just for notifying about a value chance of a property.

Comment: Clicking all the buttons which changes SelectedViewTxt did work (It updated), so I'm kind of confused by this to be honest

Comment: Also be aware that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on a OneWay Binding is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: @Clemens Okay well regardless if I'm confused, I understand that I must use the public property name in the OnPropertyChanged(); Thank you for explaining guys